# Need to rewrite C++ code to PHP

Tags: php, c++

I have a task. I need to rewrite C++ code to PHP.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Structure {
    int x;
};

void f(Structure st, Structure& r_st, int a[], int n) {
    st.x++;
    r_st.x++;
    a[0]++;
    n++;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Structure ss0 = {0};
    Structure ss1 = {1};
    int ia[] = {0};
    int m = 0;
    f(ss0, ss1, ia, m);
    cout << ss0.x << " "
         << ss1.x << " "
         << ia[0] << " "
         << m     << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

return of a compiler is `0 2 1 0`. I have rewrote this code in PHP like this:

```
<?php

class Structure {
    public function __construct($x) {
        $this->x = $x;
    }

    public $x;
}

function f($st, $r_st, $a, $n) {
    $st->x++;
    $r_st->x++;
    $a[0]++;
    $n++;
}

$ss0 = new Structure(0);
$ss1 = new Structure(1);

$ia = [0];
$m = 0;

f($ss0, $ss1, $ia, $m);
echo $ss0->x    . " "
     . $ss1->x  . " "
     . $ia[0]   . " "
     . $m       . "\n";
```

return of this code is: `1 2 0 0`. I know PHP and I know why it is returning this values. I need to understand how in C++ struct works and why a[0]++ is globally incremented. Please help to rewrite this code on PHP. I also know than there is no struct in PHP.

Comment: `int a[]` is the same as `int* a`, so the parameter is passed as a pointer. `a[0]++` increments the object pointed to, not a local copy.

Comment: Also note that the only difference between a class and a struct in C++ is default access for its members.

Comment: Struct is same as Class. The only difference is all properties & methods in struct is always public by default. a[0]++ is globally incremented because you pass an array of pointer not a copy of array. For understanding this you can learn array of pointer from google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference between:

```
function f($st, $r_st, $a, $n)
void f(Structure st, Structure& r_st, int a[], int n)
```

in C++ you always specify, pass by value or by reference, but in PHP there are some pre-defined rules.

**Fix for 1st output**

C++ part: `st` is passed by value, and original value, which you pass here is not changed. `r_st` is passed by reference, and original value is changed.

PHP part: both arguments are passed by reference, since they are classes.

Simple fix there is to clone object `st` and pass it to function to mimic C++ pass-by-copy, or clone it inside function.

---

**Fix for 3rd output**

in C++ `int a[]` is passed as pointer, so, original value is changed, but in PHP it is passed by value, and it is unchanged outside.

Simple fix for it would be `&$a` instead of `$a` in function parameters.

PS. I'm C++ developer, so, PHP part can be inaccurate in terminology.

Answer (score 1):

The `ss0` and `ss1` variables you are passing in are by object accessors to that function. See [Objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

The variables passed in are by value. See [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 0):

> Please help to rewrite this code on PHP.

Do it like this

```
function f($st, $r_st, &$a, $n) {

     $st= clone $st; #clone to get a real copy, not a refer

     $st->x++;
     $r_st->x++;
     $a[0]++; #&$a to simulate  ia[] (use as reference)
     $n++;
}
```

Read about references in PHP. I'm not a C++ dev.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php